# Oracle trigger error, 10g to 11g export

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

i am trying to export a 10g database to 11g and receieving error(execution completed with warning) at the row that tries to create the trigger.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger TR_INS_DATACARD
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AFTARSIV"."TR_INS_DATACARD" BEFORE INSERT ON fichas REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT fichas_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.clave FROM DUAL; END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "AFTARSIV"."TR_INS_DATACARD" ENABLE;
```

SQL command works fine with 10g, it even creates the trigger at 11g but the trigger has this error:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;

Comment: Remove slash `/` after the `end;` from trigger and see.

Comment: changed "AFTARSIV"."TR_INS_DATACARD" to tr_ins_datacard and problem solved but i still don't get it why. I be glad if anyone can explain.